# How to determine if two vectors intersect in 3D space

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have two triangles in 3D space with a shared edge.  I need to determine if the triangles exist on the same plane.  To do this, I need to determine if the vector between the unshared points (P1 -> P4) bisects the shared edge (P2 -> P3).

How do I perform this comparison?

[image: Two triangles with shared edge]

Comment: Are you familiar with cross-product?

Comment: No, I am not.  I'm by no means a mathematician.  I'm a coder with a problem that I must solve, so I figured the real mathematicians could get me to a solution faster than I can after a ton of Googling and not understanding the answers.

Comment: If you can figure out how to calculate a 3x3 determinant, that's pretty much all you need

Comment: @DavidQuinn, assuming I calculate the 3x3 determinant, what am I looking for as a result to tell me if the triangles are planar?

Comment: If you work out the determinant formed by the vectors $P_1P_2, P_1P_3, P_1P_4$ and the result is zero, then the four points are coplanar

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a system describing intersection of two vectors has a solution and it satisfy  a condition to lie somewhere between the corners, is not an elegant and simple method. Better compare normal vectors or zero tetrahedron volume. Cross product simplifies a lot. 
And simple check if P4 lies in the plane P1P2P3 also suffices.

http://www.had2know.com/academics/tetrahedron-volume-4-vertices.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866452/calculate-volume-of-any-tetrahedron-given-4-points
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron
No need for "tones" of googling, just the right idea, other methods at the end leads to the same formula.